# pass a command as an argument to bash script

Tags: bash

How do I pass a command as an argument to a bash script?
In the following script, I attempted to do that, but it's not working!

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir> <command to execute>"
    exit 1;
fi;

while read line
do
    $($2) $line
done < $(ls $1);

echo "All Done"
```

A sample usage of this script would be

```
./myscript thisDir echo
```

Executing the call above ought to echo the name of all files in the `thisDir` directory.

Comment: try `eval "$2"` - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-passing-command-as-string-476664/

Comment: @DavidStarkey Hm, I tried `eval` (along with pther solutions relating to `eval` suggested below), none worked.

Answer (score 5):

First big problem: `$($2) $line` executes `$2` by itself as a command, then tries to run its output (if any) as another command with `$line` as an argument to it. You just want `$2 $line`.

Second big problem: `while read ... done < $(ls $1)` doesn't read from the list of filenames, it tries to the contents of a file specified by the output of ls -- this will fail in any number of ways depending on the exact circumstances. Process substitution (`while read ... done < <(ls $1)`) would do more-or-less what you want, but it's a bash-only feature (i.e. you *must* start the script with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`). And anyway it's a bad idea to [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you should almost always just use a shell glob (`*`) instead.

The script also has some other potential issues with spaces in filenames (using `$line` without double-quotes around it, etc), and weird stylistic oddities (you don't need `;` at the end of a line in shell). Here's my stab at a rewrite:

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir> <command to execute>"
    exit 1
fi

for file in "$1"/*; do
    $2 "$file"
done

echo "All done"
```

Note that I didn't put double-quotes around `$2`. This allows you to specify multiword commands (e.g. `./myscript thisDir "cat -v"` would be interpreted as running the `cat` command with the `-v` option, rather than trying to run a command named `"cat -v"`). It would actually be a bit more flexible to take all arguments after the first one as the command and its argument, allowing you to do e.g. `./myscript thisDir cat -v`, `./myscript thisDir grep -m1 "pattern with spaces"`, etc:

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir> <command to execute> [command options]"
    exit 1
fi

dir="$1"
shift

for file in "$dir"/*; do
    "$@" "$file"
done

echo "All done"
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try: (in your codes)

```
echo "$2 $line"|sh
```

or the `eval`:

```
eval "$2 $line"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When I call the script with `myscript thisDir cat`, which means it should `cat` all the files in the dir, it didn't

Comment: No, no error whatsoever. When I ran the script, it just listed all the files in the dir, even though I did specify `cat` as the command.

Comment: @OneTwoThree 1) ls can have dir in result, cat dir won't work. 2) you could try `ls $1|while read line.....done`

Answer (score 2):

your command "echo" command is "hidden" inside a sub-shell from its argments in $line.

I think  I understand what your attempting in with `$($2)`, but its probably overkill, unless this isn't the whole story, so

```
 while read line ; do
    $2 $line
 done < $(ls $1)
```

should work for your example with `thisDir echo`. If you really need the cmd-substitution and the subshell, then put you arguments so they can see each other:

```
   $($2 $line)
```

And as D.S. mentions, you might need `eval` before either of these.

IHTH