# How to pipe stderr to notify-send?

Tags: shell, pipe, stderr

I run programs using keybindings, which themselves could call dmenu and do things in the background. I would love to pipe `stderr` to `notify-send` and get a notification if something failed.

These programs are not called from a terminal emulator, mostly [`sxhkd`](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) coupled with an `xdg-open` alternative [`jaro`](https://github.com/isamert/jaro).

Take this example, for instance:

```sh
$ ls /root
"/root": Permission denied (os error 13)
$ ls /root 2> /dev/null
$
```

If I had an sxhkd entry

```
super + Return
  ls /root
```

How can I have it output stderr to a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script `notify-pipe`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

read notification
notify-send "Command Failed" "$notification" "$@"
```

And pipe `stderr` to `stdout`:

```sh
$ ls /root  2>&1| notify-pipe
```

Possible enhancement: [bash get command that was used before pipe symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358661/bash-get-command-that-was-used-before-pipe-symbol) to get the command in the notification summary.

Thanks for the help, Ron.

Answer (score 1):

notify-send will not work with `piping`

However, you can try:
    sudo pip install notify-pipe

Which accepts `piping`

See here: https://github.com/ron7/notify-pipe

And you can pipe `stderr` to `stdout` and send it to notify-pipe

```
command 2>&1|notify-pipe
```